# how to customize a dataframe name in a UDF in R

Tags: r, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have created a UDF.

within the UDF I will create new dataframes that consist of colMean using 4 different dataframes, which one input for one output and not a combine them together.

now, I want each new dataframe that created through UDF to have its own unique naming. But I have no idea how to do that.

the UDF:

```
calculatingMean <- function(df, colname){
  ft_cate <- df[df$Satisfaction == 'Neutral or Dissatisfied',c(10:23)]
  colavg <- as.data.frame(colMeans(ft_cate))
  colavg
}
```

the input:

```
calculatingMean(children, 'children')
```

what I tried:
`colavg + colname <- as.data.frame(colMeans(ft_cate))`

which obviously not working.

Comment: In your user defined function, you have the input `colname` but it is not present anywhere in the function. Was this a typo?

Comment: What would be the output data.frame name corresponding to the input `children`?

Comment: @jpsmith no its not, I used colname in "what i tried"

Comment: @RuiBarradas I want to get soomething like "colavg_children"

Comment: @william_Li thanks - if it was not a typo then it doesn’t make sense why `colname` is in your UDF if it is not used in the function. You may want to review and practice the basic syntax of creating UDFs. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_functions.htm) or [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/write-functions-in-r/) could get you started